# I'm trying to use a continue statement with a list

Tags: python, list, while-loop, continue

```
spam = 0
while spam < 10:
    spam = spam + 1
    if spam == 3 or spam == 6 or spam == 9:
        continue
    print('spam is ' + str(spam))


threes = [3,6,9]
spam = 0
while spam < 10:
    spam = spam + 1
    for i in threes:
        if spam == i:
            continue
    print('spam is ' + str(spam))
```

The first code runs perfectly but the one after doesn't.

Comment: `continue` only continues iteration for the "nearest" loop that the `continue` is contained in. In your case that's the `for i in threes` loop

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.0/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue

Comment: if you want to check if spam is in the list of 3, 6, 9, just use `if spam in threes:`

Comment: Or, simply check `if spam % 3 == 0:`...